# Programming a "fake" router

Tags: networking

I would like to know if it is possible to write some software that could fake the prescence of a router when running so other people can see it in their list of wireless hotspots? A bit like the MyWi application for jailbroken iPhones (altough MyWi is not a fake).
It doesn't have to do anything, just show up on WiFi scans.

Is this possible?

Thanks a bunch!

Andesay

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to do this? Sorry but I can't seem to think of any other reason than MINM.

Comment: Not besides interest. I think it could be exiting to write such a piece of software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a Linux program called hostapd that can allow a computer to serve as an access point. Unless you like writing driver code (or at least spend quite some time reading the 802.11 specification), you probably won't want to reinvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't want a fake router (shows up as a hop in a traceroute and in a list of UPnP devices) but a fake wireless access point (shows up in the list of available wifi stations).

This means your wireless network interface has to be put in *AP mode*, so it emits beacons containing your fake SSID. This is rather complicated but it is actually possible with the right combination of network adapter and driver. If you have done that, there is not much work left to make it a real access point, so you wouldn't save much with a fake one compared to a real one.